# Error: Use the unresolved identifier 'indexPath'

Tags: ios, swift

..Please Help..thank you.. :D

> Error: Use the unresolved identifier 'indexPath'

```
import Foundation

class BackTableVC: UITableViewController{

var TableArray  = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    TableArray = ["HOME","MEN","WOMEN"]

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberofROwsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return TableArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[NSIndexPath.row]

    return cell

}
}
```

Comment: your `tableView` delegate method is incorrect, it should have an `indexPath`  variable, and you should use that instead of `NSIndexPath.row`, the correct one is `indexPath.row`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   // add indexPath
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // use indexPath not NSIndexPath
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
    }
```

Comment: ..thank you very much..I edit some and run..but nothings happened :/

Comment: Can you add this line before return cell : println("\(indexPath.row)") and see is it printed out in the console?

Comment: It actually work but I didn't notice the difference..where can I found the console??..

Comment: shift + apple key + C. If it works what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your override cellForRowAtIndexPath method with below:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        //Your Logic
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: ERROR IS IN THIS LINE: var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

Comment: @RH34Serenity Complete answer