# Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView'

Tags: swift, tableview

[I had an a problem with this code, this identifier didn't run with me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3HtY.png)

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantDetailViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var restaurantImageView: UIImageView!
    var restaurantImage = ""

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad ()

        restaurantImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImage)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showRestaurantDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! RestaurantDetailViewController
                destinationController.restaurantImage = restaurantImageView[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is : Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView'

Looking for a solution.
Thanks,

Comment: You don't have a `tableView` in your class - you should add one.

Comment: this is a view view controller that receive image object from other view controller

Answer (score 2):

The `prepareForSegue` method is obviously in the wrong class (copy and paste error?).

It belongs to the *Master* controller.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a tableview in your VIEWCONTROLLER ? If yes then create a IBOOutlet between your class and viewcontroller

Answer (score -2):

you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650411/error-use-the-unresolved-identifier-indexpath) question   or this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift) for reference.

This behavior is called "scope" and is crucial to any programming language. Variables declared inside a method are neither visible outside it nor do they persist when that method has finished running. and in your case for creating tableView variable you have to create an IBOoutlet or you can define it programmatically too you can get more detail from  [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/ibaction-and-iboutlet/)

and [here](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/)